# Question about react pass component in render

Tags: reactjs

I am reading the great blog and find some place I  do not understand very clearly.
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders
Here is the code snippet that I am having trouble to understand.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-performance-1-fast-sgz8f?file=/src/index.js

```
import * as React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
function Logger(props) {
  console.log(`${props.label} rendered`)
  return null // what is returned here is irrelevant...
}
function Counter(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const increment = () => setCount(c => c + 1)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>The count is {count}</button>
      {props.logger}
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Counter logger={<Logger label="counter" />} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

My question is why the Logger component does not render every time we update the count state?
How does this way prevent the logger function component change its props object?
Why do we not create new Logger props object on every render in the Counter component?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

```js
function Counter({logger}) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const increment = () => setCount((c) => c + 1)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>The count is {count}</button>
      <Logger label="counter" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

If you wish to have `Logger` component re-render, instead of `{props.logger}`, you define `Logger` component as shown above, then you will get to see `counter rendered` on every button click.

As to why this behaviour, simply because you've passed the component via props as shown below

```js
<Counter logger={<Logger label="counter" />} />
```

And render it directly in `Counter` component

```js
function Counter(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const increment = () => setCount(c => c + 1)
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>The count is {count}</button>
      {props.logger}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Whenever `Counter` component being re-render, same `Logger` instance was there in the `props`, when component being re-render, objects in `props` don't get re-initialized.

Good question though!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the explanation in the article you have referenced, this behavior is explained in detail.

Here is the section of that explanation - https://kentcdodds.com/blog/optimize-react-re-renders#lets-bring-it-back-together

[image]